# WSO2 Identity Server - secondary custom user store

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We created a secondary user store based on:

```
org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager.CustomUserStoreManager
```

but when trying to login to:

```
/authenticationendpoint/login.do?client_id=...
```

this secondary store is not hit, the search for users in not happening there, but only in the primary store defined in:

`user-mgt.xml`.

The XML necessary for the user store is correctly generated in

`\repository\deployment\server\userstores` folder.

What can be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to see the Custom user store manager you created when creating the secondary user store in the User Store Manager Class drop-down?

Comment: yes, i see it, thank you

Comment: Do you get a hit from the PRIMARY? Or does it ignore the secondary even if there's no matching hit in the PRIMARY?

Comment: it ignores the secondary even if there is no PRIMARY matching, thank you

Comment: Is it possible to share the Source code of the Secondary User Store manager you have written?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the connection with an internal service, which returned an error.